# How do I assign a variable to the value of another variable in TWIG

Tags: php, twig

I am using a PHP product called Mautic which leverages the TWIG template language.

They have some tokens that are accessed similar to

```
{subject}
```

and

```
{contactfield=company}
```

I want to be able to use the | raw function but when I try

```
{contactfield=company | raw}
```

it breaks on me.

If I set a variable then I can use the double curly braces and the functions like raw.

So I am thinking that I need to set a variable to the contactfield=company and then I can access it via the double curly braces. This is how I tried to do it but no luck.

```
{% set myvar = contactfield=company %}
```

I tried to use the dump() to guess at what the variable name might be in the context but it appears that command is disabled.

I'm not sure what the syntax should be.

UPDATE

I ran the following code

```
<ol>
    {% for key, value in _context %}
      <li>{{ key }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ol>
```

and got this result

1. isNew
2. slots
3. content
4. email
5. template
6. basePath
7. app
8. cfos
9. _parent

I suspect that the {contactfield=company} is probably some shorthand for an attribute on one of these variables but not sure how I can dig into the top level context variables to see what other data may be lurking underneath.

I tried using {{dump()}} in the template but that seems to be disabled.

If I knew how to inspect these top level variables I might be able to figure out where this information lives. Unfortunately I don't have access to the PHP environment so I have to discover the information through trial and error.

Comment: What is this supposed to be doing? `{contactfield=company}`

Comment: Mautic has a bunch of fields for Contact records (i.e. Firstname, LastName etc...) when you use the token as shown above in the template of an email you will get the value of that particular field. Think of ContactField as a Contact table and the = company is the field name in the database.

Comment: I tried doing a simple [twigfiddle](https://twigfiddle.com/) for you, but then I found there is a problem with this: `contactfield=company`  Does this have to contain an equals sign in the middle?

Comment: Why do you need the raw filter? Does the company contain HTML tags or something?

Comment: @JosephU. Try this as aproach :  `{{ '{contactfield=company}' | raw }}`

Comment: Hi there Joseph. I see that Mautic is based on Symfony, however there are some differences. For the `dump()` function, you need to browse via the `index_dev.php` URL; Symfony uses `app_dev.php`. Also, maybe try `{ dump() }` - I mean with single brackets. Also, have you checked the `_context` values (you show the `keys`)?